# modelPanel (Maya) in QT UI using PySide

Tags: python, qt, object, user-interface, maya

I am having an issue parenting a modelPanel (Viewport) into a predefined space in a QT Ui created in Designer. When I try to parent the modelPanel and run the script in Maya, it immediately crashes.

Example:

Create a new window in Qt Designer, and drag and drop a vertical layout in the window and save the ui. In the python class when do the parenting i do it as follows:

```
pm.modelPanel('modelPanelA', p = 'verticalLayout')
```

The window is drawn and I see the viewport, BUT the window is not scaleable. Which it has to be. So back in Qt Designer I got to Form > Lay Out as Grid. Now the vertical layout is scalable. I save the UI, reload the class, and create the window. Maya crashes! Why?

Comment: Seems like it might be a bug in Maya. Have you contacted Autodesk?

Comment: No, I m not sure if it is a bug..I ll send it to them though.